# What is the fast way to constraint an float angle in a range?

Tags: math

For example, I have an angle with value 350 degree, and I want to constraint it in a range with max positive offset of 30 and a max negative offset of 40.

As a result, the angle value should be in a range of (310, 360) and (0, 20). If the computed angle value is 304, the angle value should be constrainted to 310, and if the computed angle value is 30, the angle value should be constrainted to 20.

I have already implemented a method, but it's not efficient enough(Most of the effort is to solve the issue when the angle value is near 360~0 ). What is the fast way to achieve this please?

Function:

```
// All values are in the range [0.0f, 360.0f]
// Output: the angle value after constraint. 

float _KeepAngleValueBetween(float originalAngle, float currentAngle, float MaxPositiveOffset, float MaxNegativeOffset).
```

For example:

```
KeepAngleValueBetween(350.0f, 302.0f, 30.0f, 40.0f)
```

result: 310.0f

```
KeepAngleValueBetween(350.0f, 40.0f, 30.0f, 40.0f)
```

result: 20.0f

```
KeepAngleValueBetween(140.0f, 190.0f, 45.0f, 40.0f)
```

result: 185.0f

Comment: Post your attempt.

Comment: Sorry I can't. The code is also used in one the project of my company. @Klas Lindbäck

Comment: You still need to provide more specifics. Data types and ranges for input and expected output.

Comment: More information added. @Klas Lindbäck

Comment: Please could you add a tag for the language you're using? I'm finding it difficult to guess, especially with the period at the end of your function declaration. The contents of math libraries can differ significantly from language to language, so solutions are likely to be language-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't come up with a solution that doesn't use `if`. Anyway, I handle the problem around 0/360 by translating the values before checking if `currentAngle` is in the desired range.

Pseudo code (Ok, it's C. It is also valid Java. And C++.):

```
float _KeepAngleValueBetween(float originalAngle, float currentAngle, float MaxPositiveOffset, float MaxNegativeOffset) {

    // Translate so that the undesirable range starts at 0.
    float translateBy = originalAngle + MaxPositiveOffset;
    float result = currentAngle - translateBy + 720f;
    result -= ((int)result/360) * 360;

    float undesiredRange = 360f - MaxNegativeOffset - MaxPositiveOffset;
    if (result >= undesiredRange) {
        // No adjustment needed
        return currentAngle;
    }

    // Perform adjustment
    if (result * 2 < undesiredRange) {
        // Return the upper limit because it is closer.
        result = currentAngle + MaxPositiveOffset;
    } else {
        // Return the lower limit
        result = currentAngle - MaxNegativeOffset + 360f;
    }

    // Translate to the range 0-360.
    result -= ((int)result)/360 * 360; 

    return result;
}
```